# Zurb foundation Menu getting cut off

Tags: css, menu, html-lists, z-index, zurb-foundation

I have created a website using zurb foundations.  My problem is this.  When I bring the browser size and the navigation menu changes from the categories to the word "Menu" I am able to click it and choose which category I would like to navigate to.  However, when I choose a category that has four or more options the fourth and all others below that seem to be getting cut off.  I have tried to change the z-index of certain elements to make up for this and a few other things but I am having no luck in resolving this.  I looked on here for similar issues but had no luck finding this same problem.  Can anyone be of assistance?

Comment: What is it being cut off from? The screen or other elements? Better to see code and screenshots...

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar issue as well. Its strange. I tried the work around of adding an additional item suggested by [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1420325/dan) but the space (albeit cutoff) was too big for my liking. In my case it was a `<ul>` list with links. What seems to work for me is setting the bottom margin on the last element like so:

```
<ul class='dropdown'>
   <li><a href='#link'>Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href='#link'>Item 2</a></li>
   ...
   <li><a href='#link' style='margin-bottom:1em;'>Item n</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, to keep the markup cleaner and keep styling out of it, you could have CSS:

```
.problem-dropdown li:last-child
{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

And then add the class `problem-dropdown` to the dropdown that gives you issues.

If you have the time, the issue is caused by the code that sets the height of the `nav.top-bar.expanded` element. Setting the `margin-bottom` as above can make it set the right height for the menu. In my case manually increasing it solves my issue so I suppose you could write a JS listener for the event and then fix things after it. However, one might consider just fixing the code that does it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. For some reason when I click a submenu when the Navigation is shrunk, it cuts it off.

[image]

I have tried, z-index, padding, even background color of each li a, but i believe the height is compiled from JS.

A temporary solution is to add another Div to the menu.

```
<li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
```

This get's cut off, but it doesn't matter because there is no information there. Hope this helps until a better solution is created!